# Can't import Default solution to clean environment: Plug-in assembly does not contain the required types or assembly content cannot be updated

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm having difficulties when trying to import Default solution (exported from our test environment) into my personal dev environment (virtual machine).

Environments are identical when it comes to CRM version and rollup (CRM 2011 OnPremise Rollup 17).

During the import process it fails when trying to register plugins. I get the following message: Plug-in assembly does not contain the required types or assembly content cannot be updated.

There's a lot of information on internet about this error but I can't figure out what it means in my situation. Why can't I simply register plugins since it is a clean environment? Shouldn't Default solution go in just like that since it contains everything?

I made an experiment and edited Default solution manually in a way that I removed all plugins and workflows (yes, workflows were giving me errors too) and tried to import it again. It succeeded then. Then I tried to register plugins using plugin registration tool but got the same error than earlier.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I never attempted this, we usually create dev envs by importing org_MSCRM databases. I'm not entirely sure the default solution is even meant to be export/import-ed across different environments... That said, I'd triple check the installed frameworks between the source and destination OSes, there might be something mismatching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have assemblies in the GAC or in the server\bin\assembly folder under the CRM installation directory in your test environment.

Here's some more info:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309620(v=crm.5).aspx

Comment: Very good guess! I contacted our architect and he said there has to be certain dlls in GAC indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the custom plugins manually using plugin registration tool and try again